# I've noticed I tend to create DOM objects in JavaScript/jQuery and append them. Is this ok or should I be creating them in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been working on an app and I noticed I tend to create DOM objects in JavaScript/jQuery and then doing appendTo('body') like so:

```
$list = $('<ul/>', {
    id : "thelist",
    class : "listclass"
}
$list.appendTo('body');
$list.html(whateverAjaxStuff);
```

and my page source ends up just being a head with an empty body tag.

I'm just wondering if there are any advantages/disadvantages to this method. Should I be building the basic framework in HTML then just manipulate the innerHTML with JavaScript instead? Thoughts?

EDIT: Wanted to clarify. I'm only doing this with stuff that has to be generated dynamically. $list elements are loaded with AJAX, the user makes a selection which populates another list, etc.

[Link if anyone is still interested](http://tidehousedesign.com/alchemy/)

Comment: Your last two lines would be faster if they were in the reverse order. You should always build as much as you can without modifying the DOM, and then append/insert into the DOM last.

Comment: @Paul good to know but I'm modifying the innerHTML continuously using AJAX so I thought it would be easier to append first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the other answers above really persuade enough as to why you definitely shouldn't do what you are doing now. There are so many reasons **not** to do this;

1. SEO (Search Engine Optimisation)
2. Speed
3. Javascript disabled browsers
4. WYSIWYG editors (This may speed up your development a lot, and they won't work with your method)
5. Far easier to debug & get help with - If you asked for help on Stackoverflow with your code above, very few people will help you.
6. Lets mention speed again - It's important to minimise the amount of processing which needs to happen before anything displays, sites with heavy JS processing (Adverts, etc) are very painful to browse on a slow computer.

I can't think of any reason to construct all of your page using jQuery, you appear to be attempting to emulate what happens server-side (Ruby, ASP.net, PHP etc)

You may want to edit the DOM from JS.. but constructing it entirely from scratch is a *very* bad idea!

Answer (score 2):

It's better if you put whatever HTML you can in the HTML, not in JQuery :).

The unnecessary overhead in the fact that your using JQuery to actually build your pages far outweighs any benefits you'd get from constructing your page in JQuery, although I can't think of any benefits at the moment :).

Comment: Forgot to mention the only benefit I can see is you could load the app into any page or empty div/container without having to change the page source much.

Comment: Yeah all being well, but what about if you need to make extensive changes to the HTML structure? You're in JQuery hell :)

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately it depends on your use case.  Using jQuery takes a performance hit, but it may very well be that you don't actually notice it.  For a lot of DOM changes, this becomes more important.  If doing it in jQuery first is fast/easy for you, then by all means to it and then just see if it is fast enough for your scenario.  If it is not, you can go back and change as necessary.

The general rule of thumb is - modify the DOM as little as few times as possible, as each time causes a reflow of the document.  jQuery can hide a lot of operations behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

apart from creating a heavy-loading page, it prevents users with JavaScript disabled from accessing the page, they will see a blank page.